# java boxes mask not working

Tags: java

The idea here is to create a grid of boxes. underneath the black grid is another grid of multi-colored boxes. when you click a box it's mask disappears showing the colored box beneath. You then click a second box if the colors match hurray, if not then the game continues. Here is the code.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GuessingGame extends Applet{
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final int START_X = 20;
  private final int START_Y = 40;
  private final int ROWS = 4;
  private final int COLS = 4;
  private final int BOX_WIDTH = 20;
  private final int BOX_HEIGHT = 20;
  //this is used to keep track of boxes that have been matched.
  private boolean matchedBoxes[][];
  //this is used to keep track of two boxes that have been clicked.
  private MaskableBox chosenBoxes[];
  private MaskableBox boxes[][];
  private Color boxColors[][];
  private Button resetButton;


  public void init() {
    boxes = new MaskableBox[ROWS][COLS];
    boxColors = new Color[ROWS][COLS];
    resetButton = new Button("Reset Colors");
     resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           randomizeColors();
           buildBoxes();
           repaint();
       }
     });
     add(resetButton);
     //separate building colors so we can add a button later
     //to re-randomize them.
    randomizeColors();
    buildBoxes();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int row =0; row < boxes.length; row ++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
        if(boxes[row][col].isClicked()) {
          //boxes[row][col].setMaskColor(Color.black);
          //boxes[row][col].setMask(!boxes[row][col].isMask());
          //boxes[row][col].setClicked(false);
        //}
          if (!matchedBoxes[row][col]) {
            gameLogic(boxes[row][col]);
            //boxes[row][col].draw(g);
          }
        }
      }
     }
  //loop through the boxes and draw them.
    for (int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
        boxes[row][col].draw(g);

      }
    }
  }


  public void gameLogic(MaskableBox box) {
    if ((chosenBoxes[0] != null)&&(chosenBoxes[1] != null)) {
      if(chosenBoxes[0].getBackColor() == chosenBoxes[1].getBackColor()) {  
        for (int i=0; 0 < chosenBoxes.length; i++ ) {
          for(int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {         
            for(int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {          
              if( boxes[row][col] == chosenBoxes[i] ) {
                System.out.println("boxes [row][col] == chosenBoxes[] at index: " + i  );             
                matchedBoxes[row][col] = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }else {  
        chosenBoxes[0].setMask(true);
        chosenBoxes[1].setMask(true);
      } 
        chosenBoxes = new MaskableBox[2];

    }else {
      if (chosenBoxes[0] == null) { 
          chosenBoxes[0] = box;
          chosenBoxes[0].setMask(false);
          return;
      }else{     
        if (chosenBoxes[1] == null) {
          chosenBoxes[1] = box;
          chosenBoxes[1].setMask(false);       
        }   
      }
    }
  }


  private void removeMouseListeners() {
    for(int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row ++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
            removeMouseListener(boxes[row][col]);
        }
    }
  }

  private void buildBoxes() {
    // need to clear any chosen boxes when building new array.
    chosenBoxes = new MaskableBox[2];
    // create a new matchedBoxes array
    matchedBoxes = new boolean [ROWS][COLS];
    removeMouseListeners();
    for(int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
        boxes[row][col] = 
          new MaskableBox(START_X + col * BOX_WIDTH,
                            START_Y + row * BOX_HEIGHT,
                            BOX_WIDTH,
                            BOX_HEIGHT,
                            Color.gray,
                            boxColors[row][col],
                            true,
                            true,
                            this);
        addMouseListener(boxes[row][col]);
      }
    }
  }





  private void randomizeColors() {
    int[] chosenColors = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    Color[] availableColors = {Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green,
        Color.yellow, Color.cyan, Color.magenta, Color.pink, Color.orange };
    for(int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
        for (;;) {
          int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
          if (chosenColors[rnd]< 2) {
            chosenColors[rnd]++;
            boxColors[row][col] = availableColors[rnd];
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is the second batch of code containing maskablebox

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MaskableBox extends ClickableBox {
  private boolean mask;
  private Color maskColor;
  Container parent;

  public MaskableBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color borderColor,
      Color backColor, boolean drawBorder, boolean mask, Container parent ) {
    super(x, y, width, height, borderColor, backColor, drawBorder, parent);
    this.parent = parent;
    this.mask = mask;
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if(mask=false) {
      super.draw(g);
//      setOldColor(g.getColor());
//      g.setColor(maskColor);
//      g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(), getHeight());
//      if(isDrawBorder()) {
//        g.setColor(getBorderColor());
//        g.drawRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
//      }
//      g.setColor(getOldColor());
    }else {
      if(mask=true) {
        //super.draw(g);
        setOldColor(g.getColor());
        g.setColor(maskColor);
        g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(), getHeight());
        if(isDrawBorder()) {
          g.setColor(getBorderColor());
          g.drawRect(getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
        }
        g.setColor(getOldColor());
      }
    }
  }


  public boolean isMask() {
    return mask;
  }

  public void setMask(boolean mask) {
    this.mask = mask;
  }

  public Color getMaskColor() {
    return maskColor;
  }

  public void setMaskColor(Color maskColor) {
    this.maskColor = maskColor;
  }
}
```

I now get these error messages.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GuessingGame.gameLogic(GuessingGame.java:74)
    at GuessingGame.paint(GuessingGame.java:55)
    at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:306)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `gameLogic` method you have `chosenBoxes` which has two elements, but you loop to `i <= chosenBoxes.length` (which would loop i = 0, 1, 2). That's why you get the exception. Change it to `i < chosenBoxes.length`.

### Edit

In fact, you have:

```
for (int i=0; 0 <= chosenBoxes.length; ++i ) {
```

change that to:

```
for (int i=0; i < chosenBoxes.length; i++ ) {
```

I'm not sure why you were prefix incrementing `i` in that loop, either.

Comment: pre-incrementing is fine. It does not change how a for loop works. In fact, people (like myself) do it because they're OCD about itty bitty performance boosts ;)

Comment: The idea here is to create a grid of boxes. underneath the black grid is another grid of multi-colored boxes. when you click a box it's mask disappears showing the colored box beneath. You then click a second box if the colors match hurray. if not then the game continues.

Comment: I have no bias against pre-fixing; it was just inconsistent with the other loop incrementors so I wanted to be sure it was intentional.

Answer (score 8):

Look, the error message you see there, is called: "the stack trace"

It contains very helpful information on what the error was:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at GuessingGame.gameLogic(GuessingGame.java:77)     // This is where the error happened
 at GuessingGame.paint(GuessingGame.java:55)         // This is your code
 at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)            // not your code 
 at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239) // not your code
```

If you see it says: `GuessingGame.java:77` that means the error occurred in the file `GuessingGame.java` in the line 77. The other files are not in your source code ( Container.java and Repaint.java ) so, they are not where the problem happened.

In GuessingGame.java at line 77,  you attempted to access an **index** beyond the **array bounds** ( hence `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`  ) furthermore, the number `2` it the index you tried to use.

With that information you can take a look at the source code and see that line 77  ( at least from the posted code ) is:

```
 if( boxes[row][col] == chosenBoxes[i] ) {
```

So, `boxes` is not the problem ( its size is 4  it was declared as`boxes = new MaskableBox[ROWS][COLS];` and both ROWS and COLS are declared as 4 ). So the responsible must be: `chosenBoxes`

It was initialized as:

```
chosenBoxes = new MaskableBox[2];
```

Size **2**,  that means the only valid indexes are `0` and `1`. When you attempt to use index=2 the exception raised.

Now having this information  in mind  you may search for code that might cause it.

As other answers points the cause is

```
for (int i=0; 0 <= chosenBoxes.length; ++i ) {
```

Just 3 lines above!. It reads, *"while zero is lower or equals than 2..."* which will always return true, because 0 will always be < than 2.

So, you just have to fix that part and re-test.

I hope this explanation help you to solve this kind of problems in the future. It is very important to learn to read the stacktrace.

I can even imagine an acronym in the future: RTFST ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, the stack trace is always so verbose that it scares the bejesus out of new Java programmers. The fact that there's so much to look at in the error stream can turn a lot of newcomers off. I first took Java last year and trust me, I felt the same way when encountering stack traces for the first time. That all said, I'm glad you took the time to explain everything, including of course the stack trace syntax, so here's a nevertheless-well-deserved upvote. EDIT: also, I'm not saying OP is new. But the extreme verbosity of the stack trace still applies. It's just an eyesore sometimes.

Comment: Yes, same thing happened to me, until somebody just told me what to look at. Well in my case it was C dumps, which are much more scary. When I saw this in Java, I thought *"Now that's very clear!"*, but definitely not intuitive.

Comment: C core dumps. Don't tell me! :P

Comment: The idea here is to create a grid of boxes. underneath the black grid is another grid of multi-colored boxes. when you click a box it's mask disappears showing the colored box beneath. You then click a second box if the colors match hurray. if not then the game continues.

Comment: @thefonso: no need to paste your edit as a comment on our answers after you've edited your question :)

Comment: This answer, while very kindly written out. Does not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, at least I hope that by reading it I give you enough information to solve it your self. Have you modify the broken: `0 <= boxes.length`  condition already? Good luck.

Comment: Has anything changed?  Surely you aren't getting the same NPE

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for (int i=0; 0 <= chosenBoxes.length; ++i ) {
```

Your condition is always true ;)